# Having trouble getting Average based on Hour in DateTime SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble getting some queries to work, What I would like is based off my sample data I would like to get the average elapsed time based on the TestDate Hour based on a certain day. So for example, If I have an elapsed time of 12 on Monday at 1 pm, and an elapsed time of 16 on Friday at 1 pm, I want the average elapsed time of Monday at 1 to be 12 and Friday to be 16 rather then the elapsed time at 1 pm in general is 14 (see query below for better explanation).

Here is my sample data that I am working with:

```
 TestDate                   ElapsedTime
2016-12-05 15:04:47.000     00:00:54.8507507
2016-12-05 15:04:47.000     00:00:03.8507507
2016-12-05 11:04:47.000     00:00:14.8507507
2016-12-05 12:04:47.000     00:00:05.8507507
2016-12-05 13:04:47.000     00:00:07.8507507
2016-12-09 13:04:47.000     00:00:50.8507507
2016-12-05 13:04:47.000     00:00:04.8507507
2016-12-05 13:04:47.000     00:00:04.8507507
2016-12-05 13:04:47.000     00:00:04.8507507
2016-12-05 13:04:47.000     00:00:04.8507507
2016-12-07 13:04:47.000     00:00:04.8507507
2016-12-09 13:04:47.000     00:00:50.8507507
```

Note: that the TestDate is a DateTime and the ElapsedTime is a varchar (It's saved as a TimeSpan and then converted to a string in a c# application).

Here is my query that I am able to get an average Elapsed time with but I am not able to get hours based on days, just hours in general:

```
  Select x.TestRunTime,
    Avg(x.ElapsedTime) As AverageElapsedTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    DATEPART(HOUR, CAST(TestDate AS TIME(6))) AS TestRunTime,
    (DatePart(minute,Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(6))) * 60) +
        DatePart(second,Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(6))) + 
        (DatePart(millisecond,Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(6))) * .001) 
        As ElapsedTime
        FROM RunTimes
) AS x
GROUP BY x.TestRunTime
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing? I know I'm close, I just haven't been able to get the days section of the elapsed time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `datepart`. And use DATEDIFF to get seconds with ms fraction.

```
Select x.TestRunTime,
       x.DayOfWeek,     
       Avg(x.ElapsedTime) As AverageElapsedTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    DATEPART(HOUR, TestDate) AS TestRunTime, 
    DATEPART(dw, TestDate) AS DayOfWeek,
    DATEDIFF(ms, 0, Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(6)))/1000. as  ElapsedTime
        FROM RunTimes
) AS x
GROUP BY x.TestRunTime, x.DayOfWeek
```

**EDIT**

If you need avg for every hour

```
Select x.TestRunTime,   
       Avg(x.ElapsedTime) As AverageElapsedTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,TestDate),0) AS TestRunTime, 
    DATEDIFF(ms, 0, Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(6)))/1000. as  ElapsedTime
        FROM RunTimes
) AS x
GROUP BY x.TestRunTime
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be in the same column and not in a separate column and also this will work for this month but once I hit the next week for example the day of the week will be reset

Comment: So what you need is every round hour in the result : '2016-12-05 11:00:00.000', '2016-12-05 12:00:00.000', ..  ?

Comment: I got it working using the Format function in SQL but ultimately, yes I need the round hour at the current date.

Comment: Format is just what you need on new sql sever versions. See edit for old versions way of rounding.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the Format function.

Here is the code I did it with:

```
Select x.TestRunTime,
    Avg(x.ElapsedTime) As AverageElapsedTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        Format(TestDate, 'MMMM dd, HH') AS TestRunTime, 
    DATEPART(dw, TestDate) AS DayOfWeek,
    (DatePart(minute,Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(7)))) +
    DatePart(second,Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(7))) + 
    (DatePart(millisecond,Cast(ElapsedTime as Time(7))) * .0001) 
    As ElapsedTime
    FROM RunTimes
) AS x
GROUP BY x.TestRunTime, x.DayOfWeek
```